# Unable to delete picklist values with force.com IDE

Tags: force.com, ide, metadata

I was successful in adding picklist values through the IDE but unable to remove them directly from the metadata xml.

Is there something I'm missing or is this a known issue.

Answer (score 3):

package.xml, which is what the force.com IDE uses, does not allow you to delete metadata components. The only way to delete metadata components through the metadata api is with something called [destructivechanges.xml](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/daas_destructive_changes.htm).

If you want to do this in a scriptable fashion then the force.com migration tool is your best bet but otherwise you can just delete it manually through the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I remember trying this a few months ago using destructive changes and it didn't work. It seems like your only option is to do it manually or use javascript (depending on what you want to do).